# Deleted hooks folder

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have a nativescript project where I deleted the hooks and platform folder to run a `tns install` again. This time the hooks folder never came back.

How do I get the hooks back? It seems to be causing problems where my app doesn't refresh correctly anymore when I make changes to typescript files.

Comment: A manual solution would be to create a new folder and initialize a new NS project in it, copy your package.json verbatim to the new project and re-add android and/or ios via `tns`. Then copy the generated hooks folder back into your existing project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just delete `node_modules` folder and run `npm i` and the hooks will be recreated.

```
rm -rf node_modules platforms hooks
npm i
```